# How can I get part of folder path name without the child?

Tags: c#, winforms

I check if directories exist if not create them :

```
if (textBoxRadarPath.Text != "")
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(textBoxRadarPath.Text))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(textBoxRadarPath.Text);
    
        btnStart.Enabled = true;
    }
}
    
if (textBoxSatellitePath.Text != "")
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(textBoxSatellitePath.Text))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(textBoxSatellitePath.Text);
    
        btnStart.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

For example the `textBoxRadarOath.Text` content is :

```
 D:\Downloaded Images\Radar
```

I want to get *only the part* `D:\Downloaded Images` and in this path to create a new one name `Animated Gifs`

Animated Gifs directory should be placed under `D:\Downloaded Images`

I can get the last name of the path `Radar` but I want to get the name without the child Radar or even if there were more childs like `D:\Downloaded Images\Radar\1\2\3\4\5` still I want to get only `D:\Downloaded Images` and create a directory under `D:\Downloaded Images`

Comment: have you tired subsString or split

Comment: Or the methods in `System.Path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manipulate with folders, you can try using [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-5.0) class:

```
using System.IO;

...

// D:\Downloaded Images\Radar\1\2\3\4\5
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxRadarOath.Text);

// Going down up to "D:\Downloaded Images\Radar"
while (!string.Equals(dir.Name, "Radar", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  dir = dir.Parent;

// Drop "Radar" and Add "Animated Gifs"
dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(dir.Parent.FullName, "Animated Gifs"));
```

If you want to check if `Animated Gifs` folder exists:

```
// D:\Downloaded Images\Radar\1\2\3\4\5
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxRadarOath.Text);

while (!string.Equals(dir.Name, "Radar", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  dir = dir.Parent;

dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(dir.Parent.FullName, "Animated Gifs"));

if (!dir.Exists) {
  dir.Create();

  btnStart.Enabled = true;
}
```